# 1 way sync instead of 2 way sync for Docker Volume?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am using Docker Compose for my local development environment for a Full Stack Javascript project.

part of my Docker Compose file look like this

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend/
      dockerfile: dev.Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "${FRONTEND_PORT_NUMBER}:${FRONTEND_PORT_NUMBER}"
    container_name: frontend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/code
      - frontend_deps:/code/node_modules
      - ../my-shared-module:/code/node_modules/my-shared-module
```

I am trying to develop a custom Node module called `my-shared-module`, that's why i added `- ../my-shared-module:/code/node_modules/my-shared-module` to the Docker Compose file. The node module is hosted in a private Git repo, and is defined like this in `package.json`

```
  "dependencies": {
    "my-shared-module": "http://gitlab+deploy-token....@gitlab.com/.....git",
```

**My problem is,**

When I run update my node modules in the docker container using `npm install`, it download `my-shared-module` from my private Git repo into `/code/node_modules/my-shared-module`, and that overwrites the files in host `../my-shared-module`, because they are synced.

So my question is, is it possible to have 1 way volume sync in Docker?

- when host changes, update container
- when container changes, don't update host ?

Comment: Is it an option to remove the dependency in the package.json when you copy the file inside the image? The module will still be there since it is mapped, just the build will not try to fetch it.

Comment: in the end, i realized this is not fix-able , we decided to move to using Git submodule instead of NPM module. Thanks

Comment: If the host has root privileges, and you control how `docker-compose` is invoked, then you could use overlayfs on the host to implement this. Use the host dir as the readonly bottom layer of the overlayfs, and an empty, temp dir for the read/write top layer. Then delete the temp dir once the container exits.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately I don't think this is possible in Docker. Mounting a host volume is always two-way unless you consider a readonly mount to be one-way, but that prevents you from being able modify the file system with things like `npm install`.

Your best options here would either be to rebuild the image with the new files each time, or bake into your `CMD` a step to copy the mounted files into a new folder outside of the mounted volume. That way any file changes won't be persisted back to the host machine.

Comment: Thanks. I would choose NOT to rebuild every-time because i would like to keep the developer experience good and the feedback loop quick and short. I kinda get it that it's not really possible. Just hoping that someone would have some idea to get around this problem .. sigh ..

Comment: Do you actually need Docker in your core build-run-test loop?  I tend to find it easier to do "real" development outside of Docker, and use Docker only when I'm deploying more or less finished code.

Comment: @DavidMaze it's our client's requirement, to use Docker so that the dev environment is simple and easy to setup. anyway, i've decided to use Git submodule instead of NPM module for now. Thanks

Comment: Did you reach some ideal approach ? Im missing some good developer experience too.

Answer (score 2):

You can script something to do this. Mount your host node_modules to another directory inside the container, and in the entrypoint, copy the directory:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend/
      dockerfile: dev.Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "${FRONTEND_PORT_NUMBER}:${FRONTEND_PORT_NUMBER}"
    container_name: frontend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/code
      - frontend_deps:/code/node_modules
      - /code/node_modules/my-shared-module
      - ../my-shared-module:/host/node_modules/my-shared-module:ro
```

Then add an entrypoint script to your Dockerfile with something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -d /host/node_modules/my-shared-module ]; then
  cp -r /host/node_modules/my-shared-module/. /code/node_modules/my-shared-module/.
fi
exec "$@"
```